# Why don't we see Lord Shiva living on Kailash if he really exists?

Tags: scripture, shiva, kailasa

In olden times it was said that Mahadev lived on Kailash mountain, which was difficult to climb thousands of years ago. But in modern times, people are able to climb mount Kailash and no traces of Mahadev is found. Also no trace of Lord Shiva is found through Satellite images.

- Did the Lord vacate this place? If yes, where is He now?
- Does lord Mahadev really live on Mount Kailash even today?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Lord Shiva and Lord Shankar two different deities?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/are-lord-shiva-and-lord-shankar-two-different-deities)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92810/discussion-on-question-by-pankajdoharey-why-dont-we-see-lord-shiva-living-on-ka).

Answer (score 19):

Lord Mahadeva does really exist. He stays on Mount Kailash, which is currently present in Tibet. But for a normal human eye, Mount Kailash looks like just normal mountain.

The people well versed in *Yoga* can see divine Mount Kailash with Lord Mahadeva at that place. Just like how Parameswara always stays at Kasi, He [also stays](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15645/3500) in human form as Rudra or Shankara on his abode at Mount Kailasa.

Skanda says one can see Divine abode (of Kaasi) with help of Yoga or meditation in [Chapter 182](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-182/topic-1) of Matsya Purana.

> भूलोक नैव संयुक्तमन्तरिक्षे शिवालयम्। अयुक्तास्तु न पश्यन्ति युक्ताः
> पश्यन्ति चेतसा।।७॥
>
> There the abode of Šiva (Šivālaya) is situated in the space. It is not
> connected with the earth. Unworthy people, void of Yoga are not able
> to see that abode; but the Yogins can realize it by their knowledge.

Just like Kasi, one can see Mount Kailash and Lord Shiva with help of Yoga. Not only Kasi and Kailasa, people well versed in Yogic techniques can see other subtle worlds or dimensions.

[Sri M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Madhukarnath), a modern Yogi from Madanapalle, saw Lord Shiva at Mount Kailasa when sitting in meditation during Kailasa Manasa Sarovar Yatra. He mentioned his experience in his book [Apprenticed to a Himalayan Master.](https://www.amazon.in/Apprenticed-Himalayan-Master-Yogis-Autobiography-ebook/dp/B007F2I3F0)

> On the second day of the *parikrama*, having traversed the Dolmo La
> pass, which is 18,500 feet above sea level, we reached the camping
> site at around 8 pm. We were tired and exhausted, for, the oxygen
> levels were very low, and we had walked twenty-two kilometres that day
> over a really difficult tract.
>
> After settling down in my tent, I instructed our friends not to
> disturb me after dinner. Many of us suffered from nasal bleeding. I
> wiped my nose clean, emptied my bladder near the rocks, and zipping
> close the flap of the tent, sat in padmasana, my attention fixed on
> the *Ajna chakra*. Blood rushed to my head and a streak of lightning
> shot up my spine, and within seconds, I was out of my body clothed in
> a blissful silvery sheath.
>
> **This new luminous I, passed swiftly through several planes where glorious beings dwelt, and reached the wondrous realm that glowed with
> a silvery blue soothing light. Two large blue cobras guarded the patio
> of a white crystal palace.** **They swung their hoods nodding to me to
> enter.** **In the central hall, on a raised crimson couch was Mahadev,
> the Great Being, manifested as the Luminous Void, changing every now
> and then into the resplendent form of Shiv Bholenath with the crescent
> moon on his head and a black cobra around his neck, his body snow
> white, and his third eye looking like a blue pearl.**

So, Lord Mahadeva really exists at Mount Kailsh and we just can't simply see Him with normal eyes.

Comment: Perfect  answer.Its correct that we need deep devotion and tapasya towards our Ishta Deivata to experience and to see him.

Comment: You believe in scientists done say there are 3 dimensions in this world done say there are 4  But we can see only 3 done say they'd are add many as 10    things we can't see doesn't exists ?

Comment: @MirgNitin As per Puranas, we have 64 dimensions. Yes. I think through Yoga we can see other dimensions and Mahadeva might be existing in other dimensions and we are just seeing a Mountain with normal eyes. But one can feel divine presence around the mountain and we can know that through experiences of Kailash devotees.

Comment: "Lord Mahadeva does really exist" there is no proof for this statement. If you have it please show it.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu You should be  able to experience him.That is only direct proof. I have quoted Sastra Pramana and also experience of a Yogi. What else do you  need?

Comment: What does that even mean? How can one experience a god? Good scientific evidence suffices. Preferably repeatable and tangible.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Scientific evidence is empirical. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism God can't be known through emprical proof. That is limitation of Scientific evidence. You have to experience through Yoga. No other way.  Get a guru to experience him. First, you have to understand intellectually what is entity called God. Please study first on Consciousness and then Mukhya Upanishads. You will understand what is Hindu philosophy of entity called God. Then with practice you can experience Him.

Comment: So in this case you admit that there is no reliable evidence. Thusly we can conclude that Shiva does not exist. The burden of proof is on you.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu I don't want to debate here. The problem lies in your methodology. if a 2D being can't see 3D world, problem is with that being not 3D world. You can't know ultimate reality with senses. You can only experience through intuition. Remember, Ancient Rishis didn't have any sophisticated instruments as we have today but they experienced that Brahman. And. no one can prove you God, you have to experience him. There is no other way. it is beyond senses and mind.

Comment: @TheDestroyer that is fine but I urge not to assume things without proof. "Ancient Rishis didn't have any sophisticated instruments as we have today but they experienced that Brahman." No but they saw the future so they knew what instruments would be available, remember they predict Kalki is coming with very advanced technology. Moreover, a debate is healthy to create new points of view but I respect your choice and will leave it as it is.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu What i'm saying is about methodology. Please see about various Pramanas. Empiricism is what Modern Science believes. There are many things which empiricism can't answer. Let's not try to verify everything with empirical evidence, assuming it is only valid. If you say only empirical evidence is accepted or true, we can agree to disagree here.

Comment: "Let's not try to verify everything with empirical evidence" if you do not do that you might as well believe in aliens, the Loch Ness monster, the yeti etc. Until proven otherwise I find Shiva a fictional entity.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Ok. You can't find Shiva with empirical evidence. If you can find God with empirical evidence, then many would have found Him by now.  Anyways, if you understand definition of God in Hinduism, you also understand why  empirical evidence is not proper way to find God.

Comment: @TheDestroyer ", if you understand definition of God in Hinduism" well if there is no proof then your God may be false. How do you know that the god of Islam is the correct one if you only use faith? Faith can lead to truth and untruth. So how do you know then which path is the correct one?

Answer (score 7):

It needs extreme ascetic power to behold Mahadeva sitting in Kailash by directly going there. Even the diverse class of Munis, Gods, and Siddhas can't do that then what to say of present day Humans. The Mahabharata tells that only the most exalted of the beings **Nara-Narayana** can behold him sitting there. Here is how Garuda describes Kailash in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05111.htm) of Udyoga Parva of Mahabharata:

> "Garuda said, 'O Brahmanas, since this quarter saveth from sin, and since one attaineth to salvation here, it is for this saying (Uttarana) power that it is called the north (uttara). And, O Galava, because the abode of all the treasures of the north stretches in a line towards the east and the west, therefore is the north sometimes called the central region (madhyama). And, O bull among the twice-born, in this region that is superior to all, none can live that is unamiable, or of unbridled passions, or unrighteous. Hither, in the asylum, known by the name of Vadari, eternally dwell Krishna who is Narayana's self, and Jishnu that most exalted, of all male beings, and Brahman (the Creator). Hither, **on the breast of Himavat always 
>   dwelleth Maheswara** endued with the effulgence of the fire that blazeth up at the end of the Yuga. As Purusha, he sporteth here with Prakriti (the universal mother). **Except by Nara and Narayana, he is incapable of being seen by the diverse classes of Munis, the gods with Vasava at their head, the Gandharvas, the Yakshas, and the Siddhas.** Though invested with Maya, him the eternal Vishnu alone, 
>   of a thousand heads and thousand legs, can behold. It was in this region that Chandramas (the moon) was installed into the sovereignty of the entire regenerate order. It was in this region, O thou foremost of all acquainted with Brahma, that Mahadeva first receiving her on his head, afterwards let (the sacred stream) Ganga fall from the heavens to the world of men. It was here that the Goddess (Uma) underwent her ascetic austerities from her desire of obtaining Maheswara (as her Lord). It was in this region that Kama, the wrath (of Siva), Himavat, and Uma, all together shone brilliantly.

So, it is not possible that one would simply go to Kailash and behold Mahadeva there. However Lord Shiva may himself show him if one goes devotionally.

Comment: "Even the diverse class of Munis, Gods, " well the gods can talk to Shiva according to scripture so...

Comment: As always a splendid reference. Pranam Tezz ji.

Answer (score 2):

According to the LokAyata Darshana, which basically belongs to of the 'Charvaka Branch' of the Indian Philosophy,

> इहलोकात्परो नान्यः स्वर्गोऽस्ति नरको न च ।
>   शिवलोकादयो मूढै. कल्प्यन्तेऽन्यैः प्रतारकैः ॥
>
> ihalokAtparo nAnya svargo'sti narako na cha/shivalokAdayo mudaih kalpyante_anyaih prAtarakaih// Meaning: There is no heaven or hell except this world. The Abodes of Lord Shiva etc are imagined by ignorants and deceivers.
>   — Sarvasiddhanta Samgraha [Lokayata, 8]

**I personally do not believe in the LokAyata Philosophy, but strongly feel that it is also a part of the Indian Philosophy. In fact it is taught in different Indian Universities as a part of the Indian Philosophy. Hinduism is inclusive enough to accept all types of opinions.**

So I am placing this opinion of the Lokayatas which was in fact used by another user (Sagar Panchal) and the answer got deleted.

I felt that this opinion should also remain as this also answers the question in its own way.

Comment: I think Charvaka is not part of Hinduism as it rejects Vedas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I differ.Because 1.Charvaka Philosophy has some views on the Vedas as had Buddha and Mahavira.If we can quote their views or even the Westerners' views on the Vedas, why not of the Charvakas? 2.The sacred knowledge of the Vedas was to be taught by guru-parampara and proper initiation.None else was allowed even to listen to the mantras.Now everybody including the foreigners are translating it and are being quoted.I accept Vedas but do not follow their instructions--is it obeying the Vedas? The Charvakas I think are far less hypocrite than many. .

Comment: @TheDestroyer So I see no problem in stating their views on the Vedas on a site on hinduism. Thanks.

Comment: Beautiful answer. Finally someone who gets it.

Comment: > Charvaka Philosophy has some views on the Vedas as had Buddha and
> Mahavira.
I dont think Buddha or Mahvira had any view on Vedas. Can you cite any references?

> The sacred knowledge of the Vedas was to be taught by guru-parampara and > proper initiation.


When was this taught in Ancient India and where do we find any remnants of an university or archaeological dig sites where vedas were taught ?

Answer (score 0):

The term "**Kailash**" would be the most prominent answer by many, yet "Kailash" is a metaphorical term (not fictional), meaning, figurative, but don't get offended yet. Yes, there is a significant and breathtaking mountain in Tibet called Kailash which has its own marvel and significance and is backed by scriptures. Even Vedas concur with the notion of Rudra's dwelling to be the mountains [RV5.41.11, TS4.5.5, VS3.61-63] and that Uma is the daughter of those mountains [KenUpa], hence the title Pārvatī (Parvata Raja Putri). But there is no physical proof of Kailash being a mere physical entity with a geographical point that GPS can take us, why? **Then where does Śiva reside?**

The very Shaivism and Advitam thesis associate creation to be superficial in nature. Yes, Prakṛti is a marvelous imposition by the eternal Maya of Śakti yet is not permanent. The Permanent aspect is always "Śiva" hence the term "SadaŚiva", **So what does that really tell us?**

Even Vedas confirm that He is “the resort/lord to all hymns/songs”, He is “the resort/lord of all yajñá/sacrifice”, and “He is bliss” [RV1.43] and that bliss is termed Śiva. This Śiva/Rudra is Viṣvarūpam (cosmic form), Pururūpam/Virūpam/Vahurūpa (multiform/multihued) [RV2.33.10,TS4.5.4,TA10.23.1] but in total contradiction, Rudra is Sūkṣma (सूक्ष्म), which means atomic and subtle [RV 7.46, TS 4.5.9, BUpa 3.9.4, SUpa 4.16]. So how can we fit that Śiva “the bliss” on a single mountain/location? However, Śankara being on Kailash, and various Rśis visiting Kailash, Śankara and Uma dancing on Kailash, and many more events are mentioned in prominent non-sectarian literature, **so how is that possible, is that not contradicting?**

Yes, it sounds contradicting, but no. Kailash is the destination marking the end of material life, it's a pleasure/bliss state of reality. A reality that is beyond the senses and superficial state of Physicality. This physicality as mentioned above is nothing by Śakti. But as long as we are in the play of this Śakti, we cant witness (Sakṣhi/Darshana) Śiva (bliss/ānanda). But when we reach the state of consciousness, we reach the reality of Kailash where one can witness Śiva and his Śakti seated next to him. Meaning the Veil of Maya is removed and we can now clearly witness the consciousness that is enveloped in Manas/Aham/Buddhi. **But does this statement above backed by any scripture other than Sectarian literature?**

Well, we already saw how the Vedas describe Rudra as being the indweller of all and the heart of all Devas [RV 7.46, TS 4.5, SUpa 3.7/3.2, Brūpa]. All possibilities and celestial dimensions that come into being is that Rudra [TA 10.24.42]. How when all possibilities arise in Him, **how can He be fit on something or dwell in a specific geographic location?**

> Rudra is the pure, spontaneous self-experience which is the one
> consciousness that dwells in all substances. It is the seed of all
> seeds, He is Prana, He is Atman, it is the essence of this world
> appearance, it is the greatest of actions. It is the cause of all
> causes and it is the essence in all beings, though in fact it does not
> cause anything nor is it the concept of being, and therefore cannot be
> conceived. It is the awareness in all that is sentient, it knows
> itself as its own object, it is its own supreme object and it is aware
> of infinite diversity within itself. This infinite consciousness can
> be compared to the ultimate subatomic particle which yet hides within
> its heart the greatest of mountains. It encompasses the span of
> countless epochs, but it does not let go of a moment of time. It is
> subtler than the tip of a single strand of hair, yet it pervades the
> entire universe. No one has seen its limits or boundaries. ~Yoga
> Vaśiṣṭham 6.1.36 Swami Venkateshananda
>
> Rśi Kasyapa said, ‘Rudra exists in the hearts of men. He destroys the
> bodies themselves in which he dwells as also the bodies of others.
> Rudra has been said to be like atmospheric visitations and his form is
> like that of the wind-gods. ~Mahabharata Itihasam, Shanti Parva, Pratap Chandra Roy
>
> All that is (विश्वं) and all beings (भूतं) and all celestials
> dimensions (भुवनं) and all the wonders (चित्रं) all possibilities and
> diversities (बहुधा) all that is born/all happening/ all existence
> (जातं) all that has come into being (जायमानं) is that (यत् =is that
> Rudra) | Entirety is controlled (सर्वोह्येष) Rudra’s delight
> (रुद्रस्सन्महो) to him we surrender/salutations (नमो) so it be,
> said/concluded (अस्तु) ~Taittirīya Āraṇyaka 10.24.42

Yes, Śiva is the indweller of all and all possibilities arise and diminish into him, He is Prana and Atma (BrUpa), **then who is this Śankara who is seated on Kailash with Uma**, that state of reality (of consciousness) that is beyond physical and how this Veil of Maya be removed? **This must be proved by literature that is not cherry-picked by Vedic hymns dedicated to Rudra, nor by Itihasas or other sectarian literature**. Well, here is what Yoga Sutras have to say:

> “The attainment of Dhyāna Avasta shows that the mind is getting ready
> for the last stage and the real practice of Yoga. Unless and until
> this condition is fulfilled the practice of Samādhi cannot be begun
> and the real secret of Yoga will remain hidden…. When the state of
> Dhyāna has been well established and the mind can hold the object of
> meditation without any distractions it is possible to know the object
> much more intimately than in ordinary thinking. How does the mind
> interfere with the realization of the very essence of the object? By
> interposing consciousness of itself between the reality hidden behind
> the object and the consciousness of the Yogi. It is this
> self-consciousness or subjectivity, pure and simple, which serves as a
> veil to keep it separated from the object and to hide the reality he
> (sadaka) is seeking…. Patanjali calls this disappearance of the mind’s
> awareness of itself is Svarūpa Sunyam iva. When self-awareness has
> disappeared, what is left in the mind? Only the object of meditation
> can remain this is the meaning of the phrase Arthamatra-Nirbhasam… In
> this Samādhi state there is complete freedom both from distractions
> and self-awareness and the object alone remains in the field of
> consciousness… A person that comes out of true Samādhi brings with him
> the transcendent knowledge, wisdom, peace, and strength of the inner
> life.” Patanjali Yoga Sutra Vibhuti Pada 1-5 by I.K Taimni.

So Kailash in our mind is in the state of ordinary thinking, and the true Kailash has to be known intimately via Yoga Samādhi. So only those Yogis/Rśis whose Veil that separates the consciousness is removed and the true *Svarūpa Śūnyam* is witnessed this is called Darshana, where one's own consciousness is its own Witness called Sakṣhi. And these Yogis are the ones who have given us the transcendental knowledge of States beyond the mind’s ordinary thinking. This state is where one can witness that Śiva with his Śakti seated beside him (together they are Śivā). And this state is not external but is the indweller of all and that indweller is Rudra.

**So long story short: Currently Śivā resides within.**

Sources : [Link to Sukshma/Indweller](http://namahshivaya.net/suk%E1%B9%A3ma-rudra-the-micro-subtle-atomic/)

[Link to Vishvarupam/Cosmi Form](http://namahshivaya.net/appearance-of-rudra-vi%E1%B9%A3varupam/)

[Link to the residence of Rudras and their intro](http://namahshivaya.net/rudra-marut_ganas-how-are-they-different/)