# How is Mount Kailash, the abode of Lord Shiva, described in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: shiva, puranas, pilgrimage

[image: Kailash]

Sacred **Mount Kailash (कैलाश)** is the abode of **Lord Shiva**. Shiva, who embodies the destroyer aspect of the trinity of God {Trimurti} is said to reside at Mt. Kailash.

**How is this Kailash mountain described in Hindu scriptures?** (its description, its surroundings, plant and animal life etc.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two Kailasas. One in [Cosmic Plane](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-48/topic-1) and other Kailasa on Earth.

> तस्य पूर्णावतारो हि रुद्रः साक्षाच्छिवः स्मृतः। कैलासे भवनं रम्यं
> पञ्चवक्त्रश्चकार ह। ब्रह्माण्डस्य तथा नाशे तस्य नाशोऽस्ति वै नहि॥ ५०
> ।।
>
> Rudra happens to be his complete and perfect incarnation. Five faced
> Siva (Sada Shiva), has built a blissful abode at Kailāśa, which is beyond
> destruction even after the destruction of the universe.

Just after creation, Kubera prayed to Lord Shiva at Kasi, where Shiva is always present in [Saguna form as *Vishweswara*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14371/3500). After granting boons to Kubera, Shiva [thought](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-52/topic-1) to stay close to His devotee Kubera.

> रुद्रो हृदयजो मे हि पूर्णाशो ब्रह्म एकलः। हरिब्रह्मादिभिः सेव्यो
> मदभिन्नो निरञ्जनः॥ ४॥
>
> Rudra born out of my heart is the only and complete Brahman, who is
> served by Brahma, Visnu and other gods. He is inseparable from me
> being invisible.
>
> तत्स्वरूपेण तत्रैव सुहन्दूत्वा विलास्यहम्।। कुबेरस्य च वत्स्यामि
> करिष्यामि तपो महत्॥५॥
>
> Therefore, I, in that form, becoming his friend, shall live at Kailasa
> close to Kubera and performs severe tapas.”

So, Shiva in human form as Rudra moved to Kailasa mountain, which is curently situated in Tibet. However, this story happened in *Meghavana Kalpa*, which came after *Padma kalpa*.

Kailasa is described in very detail in  [Chapter 6 of 4th Canto of Srimad Bagavatam.](http://bhagavata.org/canto4/chapter6.html)

> After thus having instructed the godly ones Lord Brahmâ went away with
> in his wake the forefathers and the leaders of the people whom he took
> from his own place to the abode of Lord S'iva, Kailâsa, the best of
> all mountains that is so dear to the master.
>
> [The place] enjoyed by
> Kinnaras, Gandharvas, and Apsaras [the residents and singers of heaven
> and their wives] is populated by the perfected ones [or Siddhas] who
> differ from other people [or are gifted] by birth, by austerity, by
> their use of herbs or by practicing mantras in yoga.  The mountain
> range home to a diversity of deer is replete with all kinds of
> precious stones and is grown by trees, creepers and a diversity of
> other plants.  The mountain peaks with their crystal clear waterfalls
> have various caves that accommodate the mystics who sport there with
> their loving wives.  Resounding with the cries of peacocks and the
> humming of bees blind of intoxication, there is the continuous song of
> cuckoos and chirping of other birds.  With the elephants moving the
> mountain itself seems to be moving, with the sounds of the waterfalls
> the mountain itself seems to resound and with the trees that yield to
> all desires the mountain itself seems to be stretching its arms
> calling for the birds.
>
> (The mountain is further beautified by mandâra,
> pârijâta, sarala (pine) and tamâla trees, s'âla and tâla, kovidâra,
> âsana and arjuna trees, cûtas (mango), kadambas, dhûli-kadambas and
> nâgas, punnâgas and campakas and one also sees there trees like
> pâthalas, as'okas, bakulas, kundas and kurabakas.  And it is also
> adorned with golden colored lotuses, the cinnamon tree and the mâlatî,
> kubja, mallikâ and mâdhavî.  With kata, jackfruit, julara and banyan
> trees, plakshas, nyagrodhas and trees producing asafoetida, there are
> also betelnut trees, pûgas, râjapûgas and jambus [black berries and
> greenery alike]. Offering a variety of trees like kharjûras,
> âmrâtakas, âmras and such and others like priyâlas, madhukas and
> ingudas, it is as well rich with venu-kîcakaih and kîcaka [different
> sorts of bamboo].
>
> Kumuda, utpala, kahlâra and s'atapatra lotuses
> cover the lakes of the forests which, filled with the sweet whispers
> of flocks of birds, harbor deer, monkeys, boars, cats, bears,
> s'alyakas, forest cows and asses, tigers, smaller deer and buffaloes
> and such.  It is enjoyed by different types of deer like the
> karnântras, ekapadas, as'vâsyas, vrikas and kastûrîs and has groups of
> banana trees near the sandy banks of the beautiful hillside lakes
> filled with lotuses.  The devoted ones saw the waters of lake
> Alakanandâ carrying the flavor of Satî who bathed there and they were
> struck with wonder about that mountain of the Lord of Ghosts.
>
> There
> at Alakâ ['uncommonly beautiful'] they saw the region with the forest
> named Saugandhika ['full of fragrance'], which carried that name
> because of the species of lotus flowers one finds there.  And the two
> rivers the Nandâ and Alakanandâ flowing close to the abode of the feet
> of the master were even holier because of the dust of the lotus feet.
> Dear ruler, in both the rivers the celestial damsels descended coming
> from their dwellings after their lovemaking in order to play there
> with their husbands and splatter each other with the water.
>
> The two
> streams having turned yellow because of the kunkum powder [that washed
> from their breasts] make the elephants and their females who take a
> bath there drink from the water, even though they aren't thirsty.  The
> heavenly homes enjoyed by the wives of the virtuous  ones were
> bedecked with countless valuable jewels, pearls and gold which made
> them look like clouds in the sky brightened by the flashes of
> lightening.
>
> Passing through the Saugandhika forest that was so attractive with its
> variety of trees yielding to all desires with its flowers, fruits and
> leaves, they reached the abode of the Lord of the Yakshas.  There they
> saw the beauty of many birds with red necks whose sounds mixed with
> the humming of bees as also lakes with groups of swans and most
> precious lotus flowers. The breeze of the sandalwood trees made the
> wild elephants flock together and stimulated the minds of the wives of
> the virtuous ones over and over.  The staircases leading to the
> bathing places full of lotuses, used by the ones faithful to the
> divine personality [the Kimpurushas], were made of vaidûrya stone and
> as soon as they saw them they spotted a banyan tree nearby.  At a
> height of thousands of feet it spread out its branches over a quarter
> of the foot of the mountain, casting a fine cooling shadow. It had no
> birds nesting in it.
>
> Underneath the tree the godly ones saw Lord S'iva, the shelter of many
> a great sage desiring liberation, sitting there as grave as eternal
> time in having given up his wrath.  Saintly liberated souls like the
> Kumâras headed by Sanandana and Kuvera, the master of the Guhyakas and
> Râkshasas, sat there in praise around the solemn and serene Lord.

Beauty of Kailasa is also described in *Chapter 11, Uttara Khanda of Padma Purana*. The Demon king Jalandhara, who was born out of Amsa of Shiva, saw Kailasa as follows:

> Narada said: 29-40. Then the very mighty son of the Ocean (Jalandhara) proceeded to
> Kailasa. He was surrounded by sixty thousand mahapadma soldiers. In
> the meanwhile, Siva, leaving Kailasa, went, along with his attendants,
> his sons and his dear wife, to (that part of) Kailasa to the north of
> the Manasa (lake). Then on the first day Jalandhara reached Kailasa.
> Setting his army there, he was eager to see Kailasa.
>
> There the breezes to which the masses of the divine filaments and
> the pollen of mandara (flowers) had resorted, and which were broken by
> the showers of the sprays of cold drops, blew. Charming breezes, high
> like the stout breasts of the siddha women, and rich with the honey of
> mandara, blew there. Seeing there the planting of their feet by ladies
> bright and glossy like the asoka(-flowers), the lord of the demons
> became full of the sexual desire. The gods there delighted at seeing
> their own reflections were pleased. There, the mandara (trees) with
> their sprouts withered, shone everywhere, after having manifested the
> coitus of the kinnara lovers. There the groves of many trees were
> occupied by the attendants of Sambhu. They appeared to be as it were
> well sustained by king Cupid. There the swarms of bees intoxicated by
> the fragrance of sandal and musk appeared like the charcoals of the
> burnt Cupid, that were put out.
>
> There, I think, having seen the entire
> beauty of the charming ladies, the friend of (i.e. resembling)
> excellent beauty, musk gave up the amusement of its mind, and plunged
> into blackness. At places there were lotuses shining like excellent
> red chalk. At places there were buds moving from their stems
> resembling the cloveshoot. At places there were bracelets shining like
> rafts on the mountain-streams. At places there were bees bowing
> through the humility of the nicula (a kind of reed) blossoms. At
> places there were fresh mango blossoms, burst and affected by cuckoos.
> At places there were the strong roots of the sali rice, resorted to by
> herds of deer. At places there were groves sanctified by the extremely
> beautiful young married divine ladies, which caused a change even in
> the minds of sages.

Comment: Nice answer.Did u chk other Puranas?I think Vishnu Purana and Skanda mite have similar descriptions as well.