# What do scriptures say about Lake Manasarovar?

Tags: vedas, shiva, puranas, upanishads, kailasa

I have heard it said that Lord Shiva abides in yoga on Mt. Kailasha and that *darśana* thereof destroys attachment to delusion.

[image: Image of Lake Manasarovar]

I found information about Mt. Kailash in the question [How is Mount Kailash, the abode of Lord Shiva, described in Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15639/5212). But, **what do the scriptures say about Lake Manasaravar?** I have heard it is also sacred and those who scale the mountain dip in the lake.

Comment: Related [How is Mount Kailash, the abode of Lord Shiva, described in Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15639/3500)

Comment: I have reframed the question. Thanks for the link

Comment: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/13

http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/markandeya_purana/the_origin_of_ganga.html

https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/5

http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/kurma_purana/durjaya_and_urvashi.html

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 78 of the Varaha Purana offers many relevant details about Manasa lake:

> *Rudra said:*
>
> 1-8] I shall now tell you about the four great mountains
> and about the lakes in them, which are beautiful, from which
> blow the gentle and sweet-smelling breeze, which have rivers
> flowing out of them, each of which have nine regions frequented
> by the celestial couples, which are full of gems and sacred spots,
> which always sound with waterfalls, which are full of lotuses,
> lilies, and other beautiful plants.
>
> 9] The lake in the eastern mountain is Arunoda, the one in
> the southern is **Manasa**, the one in the western is Asitoda and the
> one in the northern is Mahabhadra. All these are full of lilies
> of various colours.
>
> 13] The mounts around Manasa, I shall now enumerate.
>
> 14-16] They are Trisikhara, Sis'ira, Kapi, Satamaksa, Turaga, Tamrabha, Visa, Svetodana, SamQla. Sarala, Ratnakrtu.
> Ekamula, Mahasriiga, Gajamula. Savaka Pancasaila, **Kailasa**
> and Himavan.

Lines 1 through 8 are particularly evocative.