# Why did lord Shiva choose Mount Kailash (earth) as his abode?

Tags: shiva, kailasa

Neither Vishnu nor Brahma  stay on the earth but why did lord Shiva choose Mount Kailash ( which is on earth) as his abode?

Comment: 'why' is not a question that can be asked of God. It is His sweet will.

Comment: @swamivishwananda There is always a brief reason behind every deeds of Trideva :)

Comment: Mount Kailash in the Himalayan Ranges (it is different from Mount Everest - which many think so) is a pyramid shaped peak.  From various records, it appears one of the very fe peaks in the world not yet scaled by humans, but we have flown over it. May be that is the reason it is believed to be the abode of Lord Shiva. Russian (read USSR) scientist believe it is an artificial pyramid.

Comment: [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15645/3500) answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

See the following passage from the Devi Bhagavata Purana (Book 3; Chapter 13):

> 16. The two sons Priyavrata and Uttânapâda were born of Manu in the womb of S’atarûpâ and the three daughters, very beautiful and fair
>       complexioned, were also born of him.
> 17. Creating then, the Bhagavân, the lotus born Brahmâ built the beautiful Brahma-loka, on the top of the Meru mountain.
> 18. Then the Bhagavân Visnu built the Vaikuntha city on the top of all the lokas or worlds to dwell with his consort Laksmî.
>       **19. Mahâdeva, too, built the exceedingly beautiful Kailâs’a and stayed there with his Bhûtas and played with them at his will.**
> 19. The third Loka termed Heaven was built on the top of Meru, decorated with various precious gems and jewels and stones. It was
>       fixed as the abode of Indra. 21-22. When the great ocean was churned,
>       Pârijâta, the best of all the trees, the elephant Airâvata with four
>       tusks, the Heavenly cow yielding the milk of all desires, the
>       Uchchais’ravâ horse and Apsarâs, Rambhâ and others, arose and were
>       taken by Indra. These became the ornaments of Heaven.

It is describing how creation happened one after another at the beginning. So, as per this passage, Lord Shiva "created" Kailasha as his abode and "not chose". Because it's his will.

One other explanation on "why he chose" is given in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15645/4732) though.

Comment: It doesn't make difference if it is built or choose. Why only Kailasa on earth and not somewhere like other planes? "**Why** did he will to build **on earth**?" That is the main question. You didn't answer it and somewhat repeated what's said in the question. This DB passage is more suitable as source in question than an answer. Other explanation is already linked in comments by TheDestroyer.