# Is there any story of any human going to Kailash to meet Shiva on Kailash?

Tags: shiva, puranas

Bhagwan Shiva lives on Mount Kailash which is located in Tibet. Devas would often go to Kailash to meet Shiva. I [once watched a serial](https://www.voot.com/shows/mahakaali/1/520611/parvati-s-fateful-vision/520769) on TV in which it was shown one Rakshas went to Kailash and said bad things to Mata Parvaty.

But Is there any story of human going there to meet him ?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8975/why-dont-we-see-lord-shiva-living-on-kailash-if-he-really-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't we see Lord Shiva living on Kailash if he really exists?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8975/why-dont-we-see-lord-shiva-living-on-kailash-if-he-really-exists)