# Who are the other people in this Shiva picture?

Tags: gods, identification-request

Who are these people in this picture? I bought it in India but I can only remember that the blue guy is Shiva. I have no idea who the others are.

[image]

Comment: First of all 'Blue Guy' is a god for Indians and Hindus, so be respectful. The woman in the picture is Shiva's spouse Devi Parvati. The elephant headed figure is Ganesha son of Shiva parvati. The boy Sitting there is Kartekayan or Murugan another son of Shiva Parvati, he is also warhead in heaven.

Comment: **Blue Guy??**..haha..The pic is of the Shiva Parivar...You already know about the blue guy..the small baby with elephant head sitting on his lap is Ganesha,on Shiva's left is goddess Parvati,Shiva's consort,seated beside Parvati is Karthikeya ,the younger son.of the family..also seen is Nandiswara,Shiva's vahana,the bull.

Comment: **Blue Guy??** haha. He is God, also Supreme God or *Parameswara* for His devotees.So, you can't call Him as simply a Guy. That is Shiva's family.  He is *Adi Guru* (first preceptor), Adi Yogi (First preceptor for Science of Yoga) and so on.

Comment: I can't understand why this question got 5 upvotes. Is that because of the language op used?

Comment: Because many of the users refer him as *Shiva* (though actually he is *Shankara*), I am putting this related post: [Are Lord Shiva and Lord Shankar two different deities?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2278/1049). That's specific to the "blue guy".

Answer (score 7):

- The bull in figure is the mount of [Lord Shiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shiva&oldid=749801916) (who is in blue color in picture) is [Nandi](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nandi_(bull)&oldid=747065295).
- The lady in figure is [Goddess Parvati](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Parvati&oldid=744614928).
- The boy having elephant face is [Lord Ganesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ganesha&oldid=747311779).
- The other boy in picture is [Lord Kartikeya](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Kartikeya&oldid=748260212).

Answer (score 6):

- The Elephant headed god who is sitting on the lap of "Shiva" is Lord
  Ganesha.
- To the left of "Shiva" is goddess Parvathi.
- To the    Left of Parvathi is Karthikeya.
- The Bull which you can see rightmost corner of Shiva is known as Nandi which serves as the mount
  (Sanskrit: Vahana) of the god Shiva and as the gatekeeper of Shiva
  and Parvati.

Answer (score 1):

- > Lord Siva's family comprising Lord shiva himself as u mentioned and  his
  >   wife Parvathi [Lord Vishnu's sister]
- > The elephant trunk boy is Lord Ganesha [remover of obstacles]
- > On the left side of Parvati is Lord Subramanya.
- > The bull is Nandikeswara the gate keeper of Lord Siva. At Pradosha time first abhishekam will be done to Nandikeswara and then only to Lord Siva.

Answer (score 0):

**Bad English and answer from athiest**

Shiva Two son's Ganapathi(elder)(Sitting on Shiva) and Karthikeya(Kid beside Parvathi[The of Shiva]).The Right Side guy is Another form of Ganapathi.The Middle person in the photo is Shiva again.Shiva is not Blue in color(Only his neck is bue color).People just got used to depicting him in blue color.

Other Invisible people.

The Cow called Nandhi(Semi cow-semi human),The vehicle of Blue Guy(Shiva).

Do you see the fountain falling from the head of shiva?Yup that's his first wife Ganga.

The snake in the neck is actually the king of Naglok(Snake kingdom)

The mouse below right near the legs of Ganapathi was also a human but after some story he turned into a mouse and is used as a vehicle for Ganapathi.

There was supposed to be a peacock the vehicle of The second son.

And another cow on right below is,Sorry I don't know him.

Forgot:For people who might ask how can a mouse be vechile?

A:The mouse can grow in size and can fly.