# What is the difference between Mahadeva, Shiva, Shankar and Rudra?

Tags: shiva

What is the difference between Mahadeva, Shiva, Shankar and Rudra ?

where do they came from ?

what are their duties?

Comment: There are Vidyeshwara, Mantreshvars, Mantra Maheshvara, Bhairavas etc as well. You should ask difference including them as well. :P ... Btw, All are Shivas. I think the reason behind worshipping ling form of Lord Shiva is to include all Shivas + ultimate Shiva otherwise worshipper won't know whom he/she is worshipping as all are 3 eyed one, all have Trishul etc.  The same Supreme Lord Shiva who is beyond the contemplation has been manifested over the world in form of many Rudras, Mahadeva, Vidyeshwara, Mantreshvars, Mantra Maheshvara, Bhairavas etc.

Comment: It seems like you got this source question from Quora, any way check this for partial answer:  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/are-lord-shiva-and-lord-shankar-two-different-deities

Comment: Suggest you check this link, whcih has info. around Shiva, Shankar, Rudra https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/are-lord-shiva-and-lord-shankar-two-different-deities?noredirect=1&lq=1