# What's the difference among "Shiva" vs "Shankara" vs "Rudra"?

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, bhagavad-gita

According to below post "Shiva" is different than the "[Lord] Shankara":
[Are Lord Shiva and Lord Shankar two different deities?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2278/1049)

According to Gita "Shankara" is one of the "Rudra"-s:

> 10.23 Among the **Rudras** [Aja, Ekapada, Ahirbudhnya, Pinaki, Aparajita, Tryam-baka, **Mahesvara**, Vrsakapi, Sambhu, Harana and Isvara. Different Puranas give different lists of eleven names.-Tr,] I am **Sankara**, ... (Gambhirananda)

However often we see discussions related to these 3, with their names interchangeable. Is this OK?

Are these 3 different entities or 2 of them are same or all are same?

**Note**: This Qn was earlier asked on Meta, however after learning that this Qn may require scriptures reference, it has been moved to main SE.

Comment: In the general sense, Rudra, Shankara and Shiva are referred synonymously. So, *using the names interchangeably in the posts is fine* IMO. If there is a tag for Rudra, then there comes another question which Rudra. If in the answer, it is specifically mentioned the name of the Rudra(Aja, sankara etc.,), we can mention that specific Rudra.  So, continuing with present tags creates no problem.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, SS Please join this room for further discussion: [What's the community's stand on “Shiva” vs “Shankara” vs “Rudra”?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63699/whats-the-communitys-stand-on-shiva-vs-shankara-vs-rudra). Also kindly convert this room from "SO" to "Hinduism.SE".

Comment: I believe you question was already answered here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/are-lord-shiva-and-lord-shankar-two-different-deities.. What is your exact question?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, the answer you suggested (which says Shiva = Shankara) is already contained in the Qn linked in the above post. The most voted & accepted answer suggests the opposite (which says Shiva != Shankara). Hence there is a difference of opinion. This difference of opinion is evident in the community as well. On top of that, there is also "Rudra" (Shankara is among 11 Rudra-s). Hence an iterative answer would be good. BTW, feel free to use chatroom to avoid extended comments.

Comment: @CR241, the linked post is already present as a preface in my Qn. Originally this Qn was asked in meta. However the community members felt that this Qn requires scriptures, hence is moved to here. You may check the revision history. As of now this Qn is a superset of the other Qn, as this Qn also involves "Rudra". BTW, feel free to use above chatroom to avoid extended comments.

Comment: @iammilind - ok :)